# How do I change the textColorPrimary in a theme?

Tags: android

I'm changing the theme of an activity in onCreate using setTheme (I'm doing that even before calling super.onCreate(), as this is supposed to be more reliable).

It does work in the sense that it changes the background and foreground colors. However, my layout has a few elements that use styles like textAppearanceLarge. Now Android's textAppearanceLarge internally uses the textPrimaryColor - which is still unchanged by my theme.

I tried to override the primary text color in my theme, but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is the crucial part of the theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.White">
   <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

The background appears white, plain TextViews appear black... but TextViews using textAppearanceLarge are white, and as such invisible (white on white).

I tried things like this:

```
   <item name="android:ColorPrimary">#000000</item>
   <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
   <item name="android:attr/textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
```

But none of those do anything. What's the magic trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was barking up the wrong tree. Overriding the colors and everything worked just fine. However, by defining `android:background` in my theme, everything just completely messed up, and all text appeared white, despite me overriding all colors (including textColorPrimary). Omitting `android:background` did the trick.

Comment: I still appreciate your answer (although you were more talking about styles, I was thinking about themes). I'm slowly starting to get it, although it's still a bit shaky.

Answer (score 7):

Just as a workaround, Instead of using `textAppearanceLarge` in the layout, (if you're using xml to build the layout), define your own `textAppearanceLarge` style in the styles.xml that emulates the android default one except you can change the color to white.

xml layout:

```
<!-- example textview -->
<TextView style="@style/large" android:text="text goes here"></TextView>
```

then in the styles.xml

```
<style name="large">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <!-- other necessary items here like font etc.-->
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks snipe! To elaborate: I'm trying to add themes to my app that you can switch inbetween, so basically I have one style per theme that is supposed to define the entire look - if the user chooses the "white" theme, everything will be black on white, etc. I don't know how I would set that up if I had a separate style for "large".

Comment: Your answer work, but it's not the correct way to create android themes, Im looking also for the solution but the forward way is to edit builtin android colors attributes for easy color customisation.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between "style" and "theme" is the scope at which a style is applied at.

Here's what the Styles and themes developer docs say:
[https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/themes#:~:text=Every%20attribute%20you%20specify%20in,%2C%20widgets%2C%20and%20so%20on](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/themes#:%7E:text=Every%20attribute%20you%20specify%20in,%2C%20widgets%2C%20and%20so%20on).

**Themes versus styles**

Themes and styles have many similarities, but they are used for different purposes. Themes and styles have the same basic structure—a key-value pair that maps attributes to resources.

A style specifies attributes for a particular type of view. For example, one style might specify a button's attributes. Every attribute you specify in a style is an attribute you can set in the layout file. Extracting all the attributes to a style makes it easy to use and maintain them across multiple widgets.

A theme defines a collection of named resources that can be referenced by styles, layouts, widgets, and so on. Themes assign semantic names, like colorPrimary, to Android resources.

Styles and themes are meant to work together. For example, you might have a style that specifies that one part of a button is colorPrimary, and another part is colorSecondary. The actual definitions of those colors are provided in the theme. When the device goes into night mode, your app can switch from its "light" theme to its "dark" theme, changing the values for all those resource names. You don't need to change the styles, since the styles are using the semantic names and not specific color definitions.